# Video encryption and Decryption in IOS

Tags: ios

I have one problem regarding video encryption and decryption. Actually in my app i have to encrypt video while downloading and saving it in device, but the decryption had also have to be done on the app only. without this app user wont play the video. I don't know how to encrypt & decrypt the video. Thanks for Suggestions in advance.

Comment: It depends on whats the size of the video being downloaded.. If the video is too huge. Split it into physical chunks, encrypt and store the same. You must have a meta file to decrypt which will tell you order of files to decrypt. If the video size is too small you can do it in a single go.. I will suggest storing the key in keychain. Any thoughts on what typeof encryption yore planning to use?

Comment: Sry sir, i am entirely new to the concept. I don't know any techniques for encryption. And those videos are movies which are in huge size i.e., greater than 500 mb like that. Can you please suggest me encryption types any how to use those. or else any example code for reference .  thank you

Comment: Consider using RNCryptor in [Incremental Usage](https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor#incremental-usage) mode.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer my library for AES encryption here, You can also generate your PBKDF2 key here:

**https://github.com/sankarNarayanan/AESEncryption**

You will have methods for encryption, decryption and PBKDF2 key generation.

What you need to do:

**Method 1 :**

Step 1: If you want to reduce the run time memory, in didReceiveDataMethod as and when you receive data encrypt the data using the PBKDF2 key and write it to file using numbers. Meanwhile you can also show the user video file.

For example first file will be named as 1, second 2, third 3, etc..

Step 2: Store all these encrypted files in a single folder in iOS application sandbox (May be the video name itself can be kept as folder name).

Step 3: Then while decrypting, open the folder in sandbox and read file by file decrypt the same and write all the decrypted data to a single video file..

There you go,, your final decrypted video file is here.

**Method 2 :**

Step 1 : Download the entire video file in web service delegates.

Step 2 : Encrypt the whole NSData in one go and store it (Note : App will crash, if the file size is huge).

Step 3: Decrypt the whole file and display the video.

Go to method 1 which I personally think will not disturb the memory and will provide a clean solution.

Let me know if you were able to get this up and working.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable response sir, I think Method 1 is best for me.. Please let me know from where i have to start, that means PBKDF2 key generation, frameWorks etc.. i don't know how to start

Comment: Please open the project and follow the steps I have written in the answer.. There will also be a read me text in the project itself ... And if you feel the answer was useful ... Please mark the answer as the correct answer so that it will be useful to others as well ...

Answer (score 0):

take a look at [PrivatePlayer](http://www.ivoapplication.com). Contact the author for further details